# Apache spark error: <console>:28: error: not found: value wcData

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I follow the tutorial (https://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-spark-introduction%20/) to count words, but I meet an error.

I'm not sure how this error happens, and it is a syntax error or my spark has some problems?

I install Spark in my local windows 10, and I add many system environment variables and edit the path variable to make sure the spark can work. So I guess maybe I add some wrong parameters when changing these variables.

```
C:\Users\carlo>spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://DESKTOP-KE0B69N.fios-router.home:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1606024486735).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_271)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 20/11/22 00:54:58 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped


scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

scala>
     | val txtFile = "README.md"
txtFile: String = README.md

scala> val txtData = sc.textFile(txtFile)
txtData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:30

scala> txtData.cache()
res1: txtData.type = README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:30

scala> txtData.count()
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/carlo/README.md
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2164)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1227)
  ... 49 elided

scala> val wcData = txtData.flatMap(l => l.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/carlo/README.md
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$4(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$4$adapted(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$reduceByKey$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:322)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:322)
  ... 49 elided

scala>

scala> wcData.collect().foreach(println)
<console>:28: error: not found: value wcData
       wcData.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: Seems like ```README.md``` file is not available ```C:/Users/carlo/``` directory. Add file in that directory and try again.

Comment: In that article It is mentioned ```navigate to spark directory and launch Spark Shell``` &  launched ```spark-shell``` in installed directory. what is your spark installed directory ?

Comment: Srinivas， thank you for helping. you are right, the reason for this error is the README.md file is not exist in the default directory.